# Grunt: Custom Task - No "taskname" targets found

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I recently created a custom task, doing the following

1. Created an empty folder "custom-tasks" in Document Root
2. Created the task file itself: "mytask.js"
3. Implemented the functionality
4. Registered the task to the "Gruntfile.js"

Unfortunately Grunt is giving me the error - "No "mytask" targets found", whenever I call the task.

This is the part of my Gruntfile.js --> init section:

```
my-task: {
  all: {
    options: {
      input_folder: 'input',
      output_file: 'result/result.xml'
    }
  }
},
```

Below I load the tasks:

```
grunt.loadTasks('./custom-tasks')
```

Then I register my-task:

```
grunt.registerTask('test', ['my-task']);
```

Can someone please help me, I'm new to Grunt and would like to have my custom task working. But all I get is the No-target-error.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Project Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
       pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    },
    my-task: {
    all: {
      options: {
        input_folder: 'input',
        output_file: 'result/result.xml'
      }
    }
});

require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
// Making grunt default to force in order not to break the project.
grunt.option('force', true);
grunt.registerTask('test', ['my-task']);
```

Comment: But this won't solve the issue. It's just forcing to load. But what is my error/mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure since you are not posting your whole file configuration, as a possible answer I posted to you the way it works to me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by rebuilding the script from scratch. Got a 'typo', so the task wasnÄt able to be executed. Unfortunately grunt told that there were issues with the targets, what wasn't exactly the case.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: happens to me all the time +1 for your solution!